# Where does my workbook popup?

Tags: python, excel, function, user-interface, xlsxwriter

I wrote a program in python that uses XlsxWriter to create workbooks and worksheets. If I run my program in my IDE, an excel workbook is created inside the folder that contains my entire project and all the files.

I am in the process of making a GUI, but I was wondering if anybody here knew where the workbook would popup and how I could make a GO button on the GUI pop up a new window when other people use my program. I am using tkinter for my GUI.

Basically, does anyone know how to write a function that "runs" the program, and where would my workbook popup (assuming that we sent this program to someone else) if that person pressed GO? Would it pop up in their desktop? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through this a couple of times I think I have figured out what you are trying to do/learn.

As to where the spreadsheet will be saved, the default location is the same folder the script was run from.  So, if you provide you script to another person, they save it on their desktop and then proceed to ru the script from there, then the .xlsx file will be created on their desktop.

You could use the tkFileDialog module and the asksaveasfilename function in your GUI to allow users to select the location they want the file saved.

When I get back to my computer I will add some example code of how this can be done along with how to make a button that runs your other script.

EDIT-- Here is a basic Tkinter GUI built for python 2.79 (you'll have to adjust it a bit for python 3:

```
import ttk
from Tkinter import *
from another_script import run_script

def process():
    run_script()

root = Tk()
root.title("Test Script")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Process", command=process).grid(column=0, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

This opens a window with a button labeled "Process" which, when pushed runs the "run_script" function from the another_script.py file.

Here is what the another_script.py might look like:

```
from tkFileDialog import asksaveasfilename

def run_script()
    asksaveasfilename()
```

Now clearly you are going to have your function do more than just run the asksaveasfilename function but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks! You have answered my question of where it will pop up... and thanks for I think showing me how to make it an executable? 

Is what you are doing making it an executable? Like I need to create 2 files? or can i just put it all in 1 file?

Comment: Hi, I had a very important question : in your line where you do command=process, what if we need to pass a few things to that function? Can I do command=process(passfirstthing, passsecondthing, etc) ? Or can i just use a get() within my "process" function and it will get it automatically?

Comment: @KennyTruong No, this doesn't build the script into an executable, it opens a new window to ask where you would like to save whatever it is your program created.  To create an executable you'll need to use the py2exe library (www.py2exe.org).

Comment: @KennyTruong good question about how to pass arguments.  I believe both approaches will work though I could be wrong.  I have been using .get() in the similar tkinter projects I have been making. Report back what you find when you try it out.

Comment: yeah thanks I've figured it out. It turns out I was thinking the wrong idea because .get() will get you anything as long as what you're trying to .get() is 0 indent scope. No point in passing stuff I was thinking the wrong idea :( thanks though!